# Why is OpenJDK so slow on an Atmel AT91SAM9G25 SoC Board?

Tags: linux, arm, java

Hello I'm running java on an ARM device (http://www.acmesystems.it/arietta)

and it's incredibly slow, the results of `time java` are:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 25.66-b17, interpreted mode)

real    0m51.499s
user    0m1.656s
sys     0m46.477s
```

Specs:

```
CPU Atmel AT91SAM9G25 SoC (ARM9 @ 400Mhz)
DDR2 Ram 128 or 256 MByte
```

Any idea about how to make it faster?

Comment: it's an embedded systems and i'm using this in a PCB that i've built

Comment: You can look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html) for some official Java 8 system requisites (read, from Oracle) but RAM/CPU seem to not be mentioned (understandably).

Comment: Java is working but too slow... this is the problem

Comment: The `user time` seems reasonable. `sys time` seems to be ... a real problem. From which device are you loading your data? I suppose its not a SSD? Is the system swapping? With 400MHZ and this amount of memory you may expect to raise perfomance from "incredible slow" up to "realy slow". But you should not expect more.

Comment: I'm loading the data from an SD card, i set 1 GB swap memory the device is an Arietta G25

Comment: did you try to install Oracle JDK in the embedded ARM variant?

Comment: as far as i know this is already the variant for ARM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it faster i used the JamVM. And java 7, not 8. With this it looks like a normal execution time:

For this i had to install the icedtea-7-jre-jamvm package with:

```
apt-get install icedtea-7-jre-jamvm
```

And the results for: `time java -jamvm -version` are:

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-1~deb8u1)
JamVM (build 2.0.0, inline-threaded interpreter with stack-caching)

real    0m0.913s
user    0m0.742s
sys     0m0.156s
```

http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/